# Seconds to Time in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, datetime, xslt-1.0, seconds

I'm not asking a question actually.  I signed up stackoverflow to give something back to a community that has helped me so many times.

If you are using XSLT 1.0 there are no built-in time calculations.  I came up with this to convert seconds into minutes and hours.  I hope this helps someone!

```
<xsl:template name="format-duration">
  <xsl:param name="value" />

  <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="floor($value div 60) mod 60" />
  <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="$value mod 60" />
  <xsl:variable name="hours" select="floor($value div 3600)" />


  <xsl:if test="$hours">
    <xsl:if test="$hours &lt; 10">
      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$hours" />

    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>


  <xsl:if test="$minutes">
    <xsl:if test="$minutes &lt; 10">
      <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="$minutes" />
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="$minutes and $seconds">
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="$seconds">
    <xsl:value-of select="$seconds" />
    <xsl:text></xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

> EDIT: 
>   Do you have any other methods to achieve the same?

Comment: Please ask the question and answer it yourself. It's okay to accept your own answers :)

Comment: You actually mean "seconds to duration". And why stop at hours? What about days, and weeks? I know that months and years are much more challenging, but why not try these too? Finally, it seems like an unnecessary investment of effort -- much better use the date-time arithmetic available in XPath 2.0 (and XSLT 2.0).

Comment: Rather than post the solution in the question, create a question and post the solution as an answer. Self answering is allowed (even encouraged).

Comment: I agree with Dimitre, You can make use of external processors like Saxon from your host to achieve XSLT 2.0 .. You don't have to struggle so much with XSLT 1.0. And exslt is an extension to xslt 1.0 which was created in 2001 itself .. try this link http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone.  I've never posted on here before (longtime lurker).  It is great to see some improvements.  By the way, I know XSLT 2.0 can handle time, but I couldn't use that for some dumb reasons with what I was doing.  I figured someone somewhere would run into something like this as well.  I wish I could use 2.0 for a lot of things.  Thanks!  ;)

Answer (score 6):

Firt of all, thank you for your contribution. There are, however, a few issues with this implementation. The seconds output doesn't take the leading 0 into account, but even if that's fixed, the output can be ambiguous if any of the figures happens to be 0. For example, the inputs `36005`, `605`, and `36300` all produce the result `10:05`.

Likewise if two of the figures happen to be zero.  The input `36000` produces the output `10:`, and the inputs `600` and `10` both produce the result `10`.

Here is how I would go about implementing this functionality:

```
  <xsl:template name="format-duration">
    <xsl:param name="value" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="alwaysIncludeHours" select="false()" />
    <xsl:param name="includeSeconds" select="true()" />

    <xsl:if test="$value > 3600 or $alwaysIncludeHours">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($value div 3600, '00'), ':')"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($value div 60) mod 60, '00')" />

    <xsl:if test="$includeSeconds">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', format-number($value mod 60, '00'))" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

This way, hours are only displayed if they are non-zero or optionally turned on, and seconds are included by default, but can be optionally omitted by using the parameter values. This should reduce the ambiguity about what a time is supposed to represent.

It also allows omitting the `value` parameter if the value you want to format is the current context node.

Comment: I had to change the minutes to this: `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($value div 60), '00')" />` Thanks very much though, really helped me out ;)

Comment: @net.uk.sweet What happened when you tried my approach? It seems like it should work ok.

Comment: **This formula is incorrect**: 90 seconds should return `01:30`, not `02:30`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Converting number of seconds to time (HH:MM:SS) in XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:template name="seconds-to-time">
    <xsl:param name="seconds"/>
    <xsl:variable name="h" select="floor($seconds div 3600)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="floor($seconds div 60) mod 60"/>
    <xsl:variable name="s" select="$seconds mod 60"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($h, '00')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, ':00')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($s, ':00')" />
</xsl:template>
```