# Converting seconds to weeks and days using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I want to convert the seconds into weeks and days using xslt. Here is the xml which needs transformation:

```
<INSTANCE cast="Duration" key="false" name="Actual RPO" trend="false">
        <ITEM end="-1" start="-1">
          33287552
        </ITEM>
</INSTANCE>
```

The value in the tag is in seconds.I need to show the output as Number of weeks and the days.

Format for Output: 
Actual RPO: 55 weeks 0 days

(Formula:
Days: value/(60*60*24)
Weeks: value/(60*60*24*7))

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370152/seconds-to-time-in-xslt

Comment: Is this a trick question?  You've already given a formula; what stops you from using it to calculate the result you want?  `concat('Actual RPO:  ', floor(number(.) / (60*60*24*7)), ' weeks ', round((number(.) / 60*60*24) - floor(number(.) / (60*60*24*7))), ' days')`