# How to get a property from the immediate following sibling and combine it with the current into one element

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm completely new to XSLT and am trying to transform the following XML:

```
<array>
   <!-- red herring -->
   <Telop ID="t01">
      <time>0</time>
      <Sentence />
   </Telop>
   <!-- start time and label -->
   <Telop ID="t02">
      <time>14</time>
      <Sentence>Subtitle 1</Sentence>
   </Telop>
   <!-- end time -->
   <Telop ID="t03">
      <time>26</time>
      <Sentence />
   </Telop>
   <!-- start time and label -->
   <Telop ID="t04">
      <time>44</time>
      <Sentence>Subtitle 2</Sentence>
   </Telop>
   <!-- end time -->
   <Telop ID="t05">
      <time>48</time>
      <Sentence />
   </Telop>
</array>
```

Into the following structure in which alternate nodes supply the begin time and the label, and the immediate following sibling provides the end time:

```
    <div>
        <p begin="00:00:14.000" end="00:00:26.000">Subtitle 1</p>
        <p begin="00:00:44.000" end="00:00:48.000">Subtitle 2</p>
    </div>
```

I've cobbled together the following:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <div xml:lang="en" style="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="array/Telop">
            <xsl:if test="not(position() mod 2)">
                <p>
                    <xsl:attribute name="begin">
                        <xsl:value-of select="time" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="end">
                        <!-- How can I get the time from the immediate following sibling? -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="/following-sibling::time" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Sentence" />
                </p>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

This is pretty close, but I can't figure out how to extract the time value for the immediate following sibling.

Comment: remove the "/" from the following-sibling and i think it should work

Comment: @Marvin Smit. Thanks for the suggestion, but I get the same results if I remove the leading "/".

Comment: posted complete XSLT as answer. It removes the xsl:for-each and xsl:if (they are not needed) and sets the end time correctly, BUT. does not format the datetime as your example, just the original source

Comment: @marvin smit. I think I can handle formatting the time correctly. Going to have some lunch and then I'll try your solution. Cheers for your help everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XSLT should do the job.

I've taken the liberty or removing the "xslt:for-each" (considered ucky) and the "xslt:if" (could be combined)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/array">
  <div xml:lang="en" style="1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Telop[not(position() mod 2)]" />    
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Telop">
  <p>
    <xsl:attribute name="begin">
      <xsl:value-of select="time" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="end">
      <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Telop[1]/time" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="Sentence" />
</p>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks Marvin - spot on. I'll post the solution I've ended up with thanks to you and Mathias.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different approach as it does not rely on the modulo 2 of `position()`. Instead, this line

```
<xsl:for-each select="Telop[Sentence/text()]">
```

checks whether `Sentence` contains text. As for the ugliness of xsl:for-each, that's the truth, but it does the job nevertheless.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="array">
  <xsl:element name="div">
     <xsl:for-each select="Telop[Sentence/text()]">
        <xsl:element name="p">
              <xsl:attribute name="begin">
                 <xsl:value-of select="./time"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="end">
                 <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::Telop[1]/time"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:value-of select="Sentence"/>
        </xsl:element>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Lets hope they never decide to put a text in the end time's sentence ;)

Comment: Let's hope they never decide to change the positions ;)

Comment: start-end don't change positions? do they? (quantum stuff uh?)

Comment: No they don't. Of course you can point out changes to the XML input that will affect the output. But that's the case with every stylesheet, and you have to know your input anyway. Would you agree on that?

Comment: Absolutely; i just think that changes in the content of elements occurs more often than changes in the structure. So there is less chance of change needed if the conditions are based on the structure instead of content.

Comment: I get your meaning and I agree that your solution is more immune to the specific problem introduced by filling content into the empty `Sentence` elements. :-)

Comment: Either way. The OP has multiple options to choose from with argumentation provided in this excellent comment list :)

Comment: Thanks for this (+1). Works a treat also. Accepted Marvin's answer because he was first with a working answer but I've learned a lot from the two answers and your comments so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I settled on (thanks to Marvin and Mathias), and including the formatting of the seconds values into hours:minutes:seconds (with help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370152/seconds-to-time-in-xslt)) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/array">
<tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
      <styling>
            <style tts:textOutline="black 1px 0px" tts:color="white" xml:id="1" tts:textAlign="center" tts:padding="0px" tts:fontSize="16px" tts:fontFamily="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"/>     
        </styling>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div xml:lang="en" style="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Telop[not(position() mod 2)]" />    
        </div>
    </body>
</tt>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Telop">
    <xsl:element name="p">
        <xsl:attribute name="begin">
            <xsl:call-template name="format-time">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="time" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="end">
            <xsl:call-template name="format-time">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="following-sibling::Telop[1]/time" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Sentence" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="format-time">

    <xsl:param name="value" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="alwaysIncludeHours" select="true()" />
    <xsl:param name="includeSeconds" select="true()" />

    <xsl:if test="$value > 3600 or $alwaysIncludeHours">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($value div 3600, '00'), ':')"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($value div 60), '00')" />

    <xsl:if test="$includeSeconds">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', format-number($value mod 60, '00'))" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```