# Seconds to Time near the full minute appears to convert incorrectly

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've run into an issue that I'm not sure how to resolve. I used the answer in [Seconds to Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370152/seconds-to-time-in-xslt) to create a template in XSLT 1.0. However, when my duration gets close to a whole number the result is incorrect. When run against values much larger or smaller than this the result appears correct.

My template is as below. When I have the Duration at 3597 the result comes out at 00:60:57 instead of 00:59:57 and the duration of 955 gives the result of 00:16:55 instead of 00:15:55.

I've tried removing the modulus with the thought that I could then just substring the result, but that didn't change the 3597 result and messed up multiple results that are correct under the below code. I have also expanded the format-number to include more digits but that also does not alter the result. I have also tried using floor($Duration - $hours div 60), but that didn't seem to work, or I formatted it wrong.

What am I missing? I don't see how 3597/60 can equal 60 especially when I am taking the modulus.

```
<xsl:template name="calculatedDuration">
    <xsl:param name="Duration"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$Duration &gt;= 3600">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number($Duration div 3600, '00'), ':')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>00:</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($Duration div 60 mod 60, '00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(':', format-number($Duration mod 60, '00'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `format-number` does rounding, not truncating.  `format-number(59.97, '00')` has a value of 60, not 59.  So use `format-number(floor($Duration div 60) mod 60, '00')` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling floor was the answer, but I couldn't figure out the format.